# JQuery Development Standards

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking into development standards fro JavaScript. I had previously used Doulgas Crockfords Javascript standards and [JsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) . However now I'm making more use of JQuery I'm looking for something that is more Jquery oriented as well.

Ideally a sensible checklist and an automated tool to validate. However realistically just a set of sensible guidelines would be a good starting point

Comment: There's not much to it really. Just follow general JavaScript best practices and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll add to this as I think of them, but here's a few off the top of my head:

- prepend jQuery object variables with a $, for example: `var $doc_list = $('.documents');` this will help prevent you getting confused trying to remember if you're currently holding an id string, an element or a jQuery object in that variable.
- Use the UI css framework. A great tutorial on getting started with it is [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/).
- Take a read through the [plugins authoring documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Answer (score 5):

#### Specify a context:

```
$('p > a', '#content'); // The 2nd argument is the context
```

#### Tab your chains!

```
// BAD
$('a').css('fontSize', '12px').addClass('link').bind('click', clickHandler).find('span').removeClass('inner');

// BETTER
$('a')
    .css('fontSize', '12px')
    .addClass('link')
    .bind('click', clickHandler)
    .find('span')
        .removeClass('inner');
```

#### Don't have massive HTML strings:

```
// BAD
$('<img id="something" src="path/img.jpg" height="300" width="300" />');

// BETTER
$('<img/>').attr({
    id: 'something',
    src: 'path/img.jpg',
    height: 300,
    width: 300
});
```

Comment: even better: template your HTML out entirely using something like $.tempest - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tempest

Comment: whats the difference between the HTML string and the attr'ed version?

Comment: it's easier to understand and sum up like this

also if you have to change one, it's easy !

Comment: besides that its easier to understand and sum up with that .attr() + tabbed, any info on speed differences?

Comment: $('<img id="something" src="path/img.jpg" height="300" width="300" />');

x 1000

will be faster than $('<img/>').attr({
    id: 'something',
    src: 'path/img.jpg',
    height: 300,
    width: 300
});
 for sure .. ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

#### Don't rely on "$" being the jQuery object

Either use '`jQuery`' or wrap like this:

```
(function($) {
  // your code
})(jQuery);
```

#### Pass 'options' objects to your functions

Like jQuery's APIs themselves. Important when you have more than 2 or 3 parameters.

```
// define
function myFunc(options) {
  alert(options.foo);
  alert(options.bar);
}

// call
myFunc({
  foo: 1,
  bar: "xxx"
});
```

#### Unit-test your code

For example with [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit)

Comment: +1 for the 1st point of encapsulating the code with a self invoked function

Comment: To prevent collisions with other libraries (such as mootools and prototype)

Comment: This makes your jQuery code reusable in more contexts. If someone uses jQuery.noConflict(), it's a bummer to have your code stop working.

Answer (score 1):

**cache you objects :**

```
$('#id').show();

...

$('#id').remove();
```

*better :*

```
var $block = $('#id');
$('#id').remove();
```

**Don't manipulate too much the DOM :**

```
for (var i=0; i<=5000; i++) 
{
   $('<div></div>').appendTo('body');
}
```

*better :*

```
var $wrapper= $('<div></div>');
for (var i=0; i<=5000; i++) 
{
   $('<div></div>').appendTo($wrapper);
}

$wrapper.appendTo('body');
```

(better solution : do not create objects in the loop but a long string then use **$('body').html(string);**

**Use custom events and bind them to dom elements :**

```
var $myDiv = $('<div></div>').bind('contentUpdate', function() { // hello! });

...

$myDiv.trigger('contentUpdate');

...

$myDiv.remove();
```

**=> all event observers removed, mem is free ! :)**

**Learn .end(); :**

```
var $myDiv = $('#id');

myDiv
.find('.className')
.show();

myDiv.css('top', 0);
```

*better :*

```
myDiv
.find('.className')
.show()
.end() // go back to myDiv !
.css('top', 0);
```

**Use jQuery document ready wrapper : (+$ obfuscator) **

```
(function($){

// $ is protected

jQuery(function(){

// all code here will be executed at DOM ready

}

})(jQuery);
```

etc

HF